# nodejs/npm - package not working when using vpn

Tags: node.js, npm, vpn, control-m

I'm having trouble using an npm package when connected to a forticlient vpn.

I'm using latest versions of nodejs and also npm.

The package I'm using is [ctm-cli](https://github.com/cyyjs/ctm-cli). This is a command line automation package for a work scheduling program called Control-M.

When I don't have my FortiClient VPN enabled I use the commands for the package, they work however complain they can't see the server, as I'm not connected to the VPN.

When I connect and then go to type the same command (i.e. ctm will trigger a list of commands) this will no longer work, I'm doing this all locally.

Has anybody got any idea what's going on here? I've tried:

- Running as administrator, uninstalling and reinstalling the package.
- I've checked the package is installed globally.
- npm and node functionality seems to be fine when I'm connected to the VPN, just nothing happens, it gives me a blank line back and is ready for another command.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a `.npmrc` file to the root of your project, where the registry points at the desired NPM registry?

```
registry=https://my-npm-registry.com/repo/
strict-ssl=false
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on my mac / unix based system:

run:
scutil --proxy

you should get something that looks like this:

```
<dictionary> {
  ExceptionsList : <array> {
    0 : 18.0.0.0/8
    1 : configuration.apple.com
    2 : 192.168.0.0/16
    3 : 172.16.0.0/12
    4 : guzzon1.apple.com
    5 : captiv3.apple.com
    6 : push.apple.com
    7 : smp-device-content.apple.com
    8 : 127.0.0.1
    9 : *.local
    10 : xp.apple.com
    11 : push-apple.com.akadns.net
    12 : 100.64.0.0/10
    13 : api.smoot.apple.com
    14 : localhost
    15 : 193.168.0.0/24
    16 : 10.0.0.0/8
    17 : ess.apple.com
  }
  HTTPEnable : 1
  HTTPPort : 8118
  HTTPProxy : 123.0.0.1
  HTTPSEnable : 1
  HTTPSPort : 8118
  HTTPSProxy : 123.0.0.1
  ProxyAutoConfigEnable : 0
  SOCKSEnable : 1
  SOCKSPort : 8119
  SOCKSProxy : 123.0.0.1
}
```

then get these values from that list:

HTTPProxy : 123.0.0.1
HTTPPort : 8118

then include them in this command:

```
npm config set proxy http://123.0.0.1:8118
```

note*
if permission problem occures then first run:
sudo -s

if problem still occurs then include this:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://123.0.0.1:8118
```

reference:
https://www.sneppets.com/angular/how-to-make-npm-install-command-to-work-behind-proxy/